# How to hide system navigation bar in xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am unable to find a method that hides the system navigation bar. I have an app that has video in it. When the app is in full-screen mode, I would like to lower the system bar including the home, back, and overview buttons, so there's a real full-screen experience. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: okay, I've found that SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation can do this but I don't know how to use it because even docs doesn't have any sample codes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did it this way:

```
SystemUiFlags hideNav = SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
            hideBar.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
```

but it's deprecated, so here's an actual way to do this:

```
                IWindowInsetsController insetsController = hideBar.Window.InsetsController;     //actual way to hide navBar
            if (insetsController != null)
            {
                insetsController.Hide(WindowInsets.Type.NavigationBars());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have an app which has video in it and when it goes fullscreen I'd like the lower system bar (with buttons home, back, overview) to hide so there's a real fullscreen experience.

In MainActivity.cs, you can override `OnWindowFocusChanged()`, make the top status and bottom system nav bars disappear as required to achieve full screen.

```
  public override void OnWindowFocusChanged(bool hasFocus)
    {
        base.OnWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        if (hasFocus)
        {
            var uiOptions =
              SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation |
              SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation |
              SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen |
              SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen |
              SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable |
              SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;

            Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why suggest/recommend deprecated methods when Xamarin.AndroidX.Core 1.5.0 already has the new WindowCompat versions available. That just means more work for the guy asking the question

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to hide the navigation and display the application as a full screen.

`MainActivity.cs` file:

```cs
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            // to hide the navigation bar
            decorview = Window.DecorView;
            decorview.ViewTreeObserver.AddOnGlobalLayoutListener(new mOnGlobalLayoutListener());
        }

        public static int screenheight;
        public static View decorview;
        public class mOnGlobalLayoutListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnGlobalLayoutListener
        {
            public void OnGlobalLayout()
            {
                Rect r = new Rect();
                var keypadHeight = MainActivity.screenheight - r.Bottom;
                if (keypadHeight <= MainActivity.screenheight * 0.15)
                {
                    var uiOptions =
                        SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation |
                        SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation |
                        SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen |
                        SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen |
                        SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable |
                        SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;

                    MainActivity.decorview.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the compat version

WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsControllerCompat = WindowCompat.GetInsetsController(Activity!.Window!, Activity!.Window!.DecorView);
windowInsetsControllerCompat.SystemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BehaviorShowTransientBarsBySwipe;
windowInsetsControllerCompat!.Hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.StatusBars() | WindowInsetsCompat.Type.NavigationBars());

Something like the above. Just remove WindowInsetsCompat.Type.StatusBars() if you only want to hide the NavigationBar